# converting byte to str python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, decode, python-unicode

I have a dictionary

```
k ={'Creator': '\xfe\xff\x00M\x00i\x00c\x00r\x00o\x00s\x00o\x00f\x00t\x00\xae\x00 \x00O\x00f\x00f\x00i\x00c\x00e\x00 \x00W\x00o\x00r\x00d\x00 \x002\x000\x000\x007'}
```

which is containing metadata of a pdf. In the pdf properties the Creator is Microsoft Office Word 2007. I am unable to convert `k['Creator']` to 'Microsoft Office Word 2007' as in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives the required string.

Code :

```
>>> print(k['Creator'].decode('utf16','ignore')).encode('utf-8') 
Microsoft® Office Word 2007 
>>> type((k['Creator'].decode('utf16','ignore')).encode('utf-8')) 
<type 'str'>
```

Answer (score 3):

The data is encoded to UTF-16. Decode it:

```
print k['Creator'].decode('utf16')
```

This produces a `unicode` value; your console may or may not be able to handle the non-ASCII `®` codepoint that includes.

Demo:

```
>>> k ={'Creator': '\xfe\xff\x00M\x00i\x00c\x00r\x00o\x00s\x00o\x00f\x00t\x00\xae\x00 \x00O\x00f\x00f\x00i\x00c\x00e\x00 \x00W\x00o\x00r\x00d\x00 \x002\x000\x000\x007'}
>>> print k['Creator'].decode('utf16')
Microsoft® Office Word 2007
```

Comment: The output is :: u'Microsoft\xae Office Word 2007'.It is type unicode not string.

Comment: @prateek: yes, that's the point. You have a `unicode` object after decoding. You can encode that again to a different encoding, but that depends on what you are going to *do* with the value.

Comment: @Martin Thanks for your help but i wanted to convert the data in bytes to string, i have found the code which i posted below